# Lost bash got jailshell on shared host reboot - how to get bash back?

Tags: bash, shared-hosting

A few days ago my shared hosting ISP apparently had server issues and ever since I get jailshell rather than bash when connecting with .ssh.

After three tech troubleshooting sessions, they have not been able to restore my bash capability. They say they get bash if they log in. They seem to keep trying ineffective measures, and provide no details about them.

During the server restart I had tried to log in, and saw the jailshell then. Could that attempted login during server restart have caused this issue?

In any case, advice would be appreciated on how I can get bash back or tell them what to try on their side. Are there useful questions to ask, or things to suggest to them to try to resolve this?

Multiple machines have been used with .ssh with same results. I can FTP into my account (if going to root I see just a few jailshell files; if going directly to folder and then up to root I see all my files; the web serving is not affected).

-Ken

Comment: This question is offtopic here. Maybe [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/tour) would be a better place. However, don't be surprised if you get an answer "change your ISP".

Comment: It turns out that the ISP had removed shell access from shared servers, as was eventually determined through hours on the phone and finding a rep who found a tech who knew that. Apparently they did not tell their own support reps. But then about a week later, after an announced service period, shell access returned. I'll just chalk this up to their incompetence one way or another. But yes, time to find another ISP.